# Logging Fatal Exception

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, exception

Im trying to log an exception when my application crashes. Despite catching most exceptions every once in a while my app crashes. And I cant really figure out how to log the exception to a textfile. Whatever I try doesnt seem to work. Im not sure what Im doing wrong and would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

This is how my code currently looks. And Im using a multithreaded environment.

```
        public MainWindow()
        {
            AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
            currentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(MyHandler);
            InitializeComponent();          
        }

        static void MyHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
        {
            Exception e = (Exception)args.ExceptionObject;
            using (StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText("ExceptionsLog.txt"))
            {
                DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
                writer.WriteLine("Time {0} Exception: {1} Runtime termination: {2}", time, e.Message, args.IsTerminating);
            }
        }
```

Comment: That looks right to me.  What doesn't work?  Does the method not get called?  Or does it not work?  (Side note: I recommend writing the entire exception to the log file, not just the message.  So change "e.Message" to just "e")

Comment: Somehow the textfile is empty. I just get the usual MessageBox the application has stopped working but no log :/

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in MyHandler, does it even get there?  Can you step through it and see what happens?

Comment: Maybe try making the StreamWriter auto flush.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make sure to flush your `StreamWriter`.

Second, there may be other exceptions which aren't reported by `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`.

- If you're using tasks, they may cause `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` event to fire.
- If you're using WPF, you may also want to handle `Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException` event which allows to prevent process from crashing.
- If you're using multiple app domains, exceptions in them aren't handled by the current domain.